# resize menu logo according width size on mobile version of webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a menu layout like:

```
<body>
<header id="wrapper">
  <!-- start header -->
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <h1 id="logo" class="alignleft"> <a href="index.html">index.html</a> </h1>
    <nav class="alignright">
      <ul id="nav">

        <li><a href="#test">111111</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">22222</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">33333</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</header>

    <div class="section ancor">
  <div class="first-heading">
    <div class="clearfix">
      </div>   
      </div>   
        </div>   

</body>
```

And I want to resize logo image of size 450x159 for mobile version

so i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $width = $('#logo').width();
     $('#logo img').css({
        'max-width' : $width , 'height' : 'auto'
          });
     });
```

but it is not working, maybe I am missing something I tried to see results with 
http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ but image is still very big and making things nasty.

Could you please help me solve the resizing issue?
[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBYYm/5/)

Or do I have to solve it with several:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx) {

}
```

IF SO, hOW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do this. You need to load the logo in as a background image attached to a div. Depending on what viewport size is active, you load in a different background image.

```
<div id="logo"></div>

/* default styles */
#logo {
 background: url(logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
 display: block;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100px;
}

/* mobile styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx) {

 #logo {
  background: url(logo-small.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an image in your markup, so `$('#logo img')` will find nothing. You use CSS background and you can't change the size of the background image from CSS (at least I don't know how to do this).

One option is to use different image files for different resolutions and utilise @media queries.

Another option is to use the actual `<img>` tag and resize the image on `window.resize`. I'd rather use the @media queries.

Comment: could you please post an example of doing  this?, for `@media only screen and (max-width: 240px) {
  h1#logo { 
display:inline-block; 
margin-left:?px; 
margin-top: ?px; }

h1#logo a { 
display:block; 
width: 100% ?; 
height:100% ?; 
text-indent:-9999px; 
text-decoration:none; 
background:url(http://siccorporativo.com.mx/230.png) left top no-repeat;
} `
}

Comment: Have a read here - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/ and here - http://csswizardry.com/2011/07/responsive-images-right-now/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for all of my mobile sites:

```
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

That should work.